# Create object from reading files

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to use data extract from a file and create an object with it.

an example of the data: ACB,20170327,0.058,0.058,0.058,0.058,175116

This is the format of the data :
stock_code,date,opening_price,high_price,low_price,closing_price,volume

I'm trying to create an object something like this:

stock_code = TradingData(date, opening_price, high_price, low_price, closing_price, volume)

this is what I got so far

```
class TradingData(object) :
    """Stock market data for a single day of trading for one stock.

        The trading data includes the:
        Date of trading
        Value of opening (first) trade
        Value of highest trade
        Value of lowest trade
        Value of closing (final) trade
        Volume of shares traded
    """
    def __init__(self, date, day_open, day_high, day_low, day_close, volume):
        """
        Parameters:
            date (str): Date in yyyymmdd format.
            day_open (float): Dollar value of the first trade of the day.
            day_high (float): Dollar value of the highest trade of the day.
            day_low  (float): Dollar value of the lowest trade of the day.
            day_close (float): Dollar value of the last trade of the day.
            volume (int): The number of shares traded on this day.
        """
        self._date = date
        self._open = day_open
        self._high = day_high
        self._low = day_low
        self._close = day_close
        self._volume = volume

    def get_date(self) :
        """(str) The date of this day of trading."""
        return self._date

    def set_date(self, date) :
        self._date = date

    def get_open(self) :
        """(float) Value of the opening trade of the day."""
        return self._open

    def set_open(self, day_open) :
        self._open = day_open

    def get_high(self) :
        """(float) Value of highest trade of the day."""
        return self._high

    def set_high(self, day_high) :
        self._high = day_high

    def get_low(self) :
        """(float) Value of lowest trade of the day."""
        return self._low

    def set_low(self, day_low) :
        self._low = day_low

    def get_close(self) :
        """(float) Value of final trade of the day."""
        return self._close

    def set_close(self, day_close) :
        self._close = day_close

    def get_volume(self) :
        """(int) Value of highest trade of the day."""
        return self._volume

    def set_volume(self, volume) :
        self._volume = volume

class Loader(object) :
    """Abstract class defining basic process of loading trading data."""

    def __init__(self, filename, stocks) :
        """Data is loaded on object creation.

           Parameters:
           filename (str): Name of the file from which to load data.
           stocks (StockCollection): Collection of existing stock market data 
           to which the new data will be added.
        """
    self._stocks = stocks
    with open(filename, "r") as file :
        self._process(file)

def _process(self, file) :
    """Load and parse the stock market data from 'file'."""
    raise NotImplementedError()



class LoadCSV(Loader):
    def __init__(self, filename, stocks):
        super().__init__(filename, stocks)

    def _process(self, file):
        for stock in file:
            stock.split(',')[0] = stocks.TradingData(stock.split(',')[1],
                                                     stock.split(',')[2],
                                                     stock.split(',')[3],
                                                     stock.split(',')[4],
                                                     stock.split(',')[5],
                                                     stock.split(',')[6])
        print(stocks.split(',')[0].TradingData())
```

Comment: What have you tried so far in the code?

Comment: I tried something like: 
for stock in file:
    stock.split(',')[0] = TradingData(stock.split(',')[1],
                                                      stock.split(',')[2],
                                                      stock.split(',')[3],
                                                      stock.split(',')[4],
                                                      stock.split(',')[5],
                                                      stock.split(',')[6])

Answer (score 1):

```
for stock in file:
    parse_trading_data(stock)

def parse_trading_data(stock):
    str_arr = stock.split(',')
    data = {
               "date": str_arr[0],

                    ...

           }
   return TradingData(data)
```

Something like this?